# Standardizing priors in rstanarm Bayesian regressions

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan, rstanarm

I am not sure if my results can be trusted.

Let's say I fitted this model with informative priors:

```
library(rstanarm)
data <- iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width")]
model1 <- stan_glm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris, prior=normal(2, 3, autoscale=FALSE))
```

I would like, then, to *update* the model with standardized data, to see how standardization change the coefs.

```
model2 <- update(model1, data=as.data.frame(scale(iris)))
```

However, I am concerned that the results of model2 cannot be "trusted" as they might be wrongly (i.e., unwantedly) biased as they take into account the non-standardized priors set for model1.

Is there a way to "standardize" the priors so that I can pass them to the `update` function so that the priors set of model1 are, *mutatis mutandis*, equivalent to those in model2?

Note: due to the nature of my analysis, I cannot avoid the use of `update`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you originally specify `autoscale = FALSE` when you call `normal` or some other prior function, and then try to `update` with different or transformed data, I doubt the scale of the priors would be calibrated properly the second time. But if you specify `autoscale = TRUE`, then it essentially scales the priors internally to be in standardized units, in which case updating with new data would be fine, although the internal rescaling would be different.

Comment: Okay, if I understand, it is mandatory to specify `autoscale=TRUE` in the initial model for before further updating with different data.

Comment: Mandatory would probably be an overly strong word, but if you are going to update the data and the updated data has different scales and if you are not using `autoscale = TRUE` and if you are not using `QR = TRUE`, then you should also change `prior` when you call `update`.